# spark structured streaming exception : Append output mode not supported without watermark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have performed a simple group by operation on year and do some aggregation as below. I tried to append the result to hdfs path as shown below. I am getting error saying,

```
   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported 
   when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets 
   without watermark;;
   Aggregate [year#88], [year#88, sum(rating#89) AS rating#173, 
   sum(cast(duration#90 as bigint)) AS duration#175L]
   +- EventTimeWatermark event_time#96: timestamp, interval 10 seconds
```

below is my code. can someone please help

```
    val spark =SparkSession.builder().appName("mddd").
    enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").
    config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").
    config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "/user/sa/sparkCheckpoint").
    config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields",100).
    getOrCreate()

    val mySchema = StructType(Array(
     StructField("id", IntegerType),
     StructField("name", StringType),
     StructField("year", IntegerType),
     StructField("rating", DoubleType),
     StructField("duration", IntegerType)
    ))

    val xmlData = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(mySchema).csv("file:///home/sa/kafdata/") 
    import java.util.Calendar
    val df_agg_without_time= xmlData.withColumn("event_time", to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID()))

    val df_agg_with_time = df_agg_without_time.withWatermark("event_time", "10 seconds").groupBy($"year").agg(sum($"rating").as("rating"),sum($"duration").as("duration"))
    val cop = df_agg_with_time.withColumn("column_name_with", to_json(struct($"window")))

    df_agg_with_time.writeStream.outputMode("append").partitionBy("year").format("csv").
    option("path", "hdfs://dio/apps/hive/warehouse/gt.db/sample_mov/").start()
```

my input is in csv format

```
    id,name,year,rating,duration
    1,The Nightmare Before Christmas,1993,3.9,4568
    2,The Mummy,1993,3.5,4388
    3,Orphans of the Storm,1921,3.2,9062
    4,The Object of Beauty,1921,2.8,6150
    5,Night Tide,1963,2.8,5126
    6,One Magic Christmas,1963,3.8,5333
    7,Muriel's Wedding,1963,3.5,6323
    8,Mother's Boys,1963,3.4,5733
```

my expected output should be in hdfs with partition on year

```
    year,rating,duration
    1993,7.4,8956
    1921,6.0,15212
    1963,10.7,17389
```

I am really not sure whats wrong with my approach. please help

Comment: It's an unusual approach to do this on year. Also, what if a second invocation has also some data for another year that has already been written?

Comment: regarding "second execution".. am thinking of calling 1 spark sql job to aggregate data finally... is there any alternatives ?

Comment: OK, just finished watching PrisonBreak and updated answer. Not sure about your final use case.

Comment: So..what do you think..should i use spark structured streaming or spark streaming.... I will get data every 30 seconds... And i need to apply aggregations and write to hive table... For example.. Within 1 minute i will append aggregated results 3 times to hive...as and when it process....

Comment: Spark Streaming is being deprecated, but there is more to consider than just that.

Comment: Here is the link..     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54161205/hdfs-files-not-getting-updated-after-each-batch-on-spark-structured-streaming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question with many aspects:

- The Structured Streaming API has limitations imho.
- One can pipeline multiple queries and technically it runs, but produces no output, so it is of no value to do that - and it cannot perform such other functionality even though you can specify it.
- The manual states: withWatermark must be called on the same column as the timestamp
  column used in the aggregate.

  > For example, df.withWatermark("time", "1
  >   min").groupBy("time2").count() is invalid in Append output mode, as
  >   watermark is defined on a different column from the aggregation
  >   column.
  >   Simply stated, for Append you need WaterMark.
  >   I think you have an issue here.
- Is the following relavant when using path?

> ```
>   .enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
>   .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
> ```

- Also, your final use case is not known. The question here is whether this is a good approach, but there is too little insight for me to assess, we simply assume it to be so.
- We are assuming that Ratings for same movie will be part of a future microbatch.
- There is a lack of an event_time in the feed, but you create it yourself. Somewhat unrealistic, but OK we can live with that, although TimeStamp is a little problematic.
- I advise you look at this blog http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-spark-structured-streaming-part-12/ for an excellent assessment of Structured Streaming.

**So, in general:**

- Of the options Complete, Append and Update I think you have chosen the right one Append.  Update could be used but I leave that out of scope.
- But did not put event_time in a Window. You should do this. I have put an example at the end here, run in Spark Shell where I could not get case class to work - that's why it took so long, but in a compiled program its is not an issue, or DataBricks.
- You cannot, functionally, write multiple queries to do the aggregation that you tried. It just produces in my case some errors.
- I would advise you use the timestamp approach I used, it is easier, as I could not test all your stuff.

**Then:**

- Either, write the output of this module to a KAFKA Topic and read that Topic into another module and do the second aggregation and write out, taking into account that you can get multiple movie ratings in different microbatches.
- Or, write the data out as it is including a count field, and then provide a view layer for querying that takes into account the fact that there were multiple writes.

Here is a sample using socket input and the Spark Shell - that you can extrapolate to your own data, and the output of a microbatch (note there are delays in seeing the data):

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("example")
  .getOrCreate()
//create stream from socket

import sparkSession.implicits._
sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
val socketStreamDs = sparkSession.readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", "localhost")
  .option("port", 9999)
  .load()
  .as[String]

val stockDs = socketStreamDs.map(value => (value.trim.split(","))).map(entries=>(new java.sql.Timestamp(entries(0).toLong),entries(1),entries(2).toDouble)).toDF("time","symbol","value")//.toDS() 

val windowedCount = stockDs
  .withWatermark("time", "20000 milliseconds")
  .groupBy( 
    window($"time", "10 seconds"),
           $"symbol" 
  )
  .agg(sum("value"), count($"symbol"))

val query =
  windowedCount.writeStream
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate", "false")
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())

query.start().awaitTermination()
```

results in:

```
Batch: 14
----------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+  
|window                                       |symbol|sum(value)|count(symbol)|
+---------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|[2016-04-27 04:34:20.0,2016-04-27 04:34:30.0]|"aap1"|4200.0    |6            |
|[2016-04-27 04:34:30.0,2016-04-27 04:34:40.0]|"app1"|800.0     |2            |
|[2016-04-27 04:34:20.0,2016-04-27 04:34:30.0]|"aap2"|2500.0    |1            |
|[2016-04-27 04:34:40.0,2016-04-27 04:34:50.0]|"app1"|2800.0    |4            |
+---------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

It's quite a big topic and you need to look at it holistically.

You can see for the output that having a count could be handy in some cases, although avg output can be used to count overall avg. Success.

Comment: i need to group by based on year and taking sum out of that...i am getting error  if i ddnt use watermark... is there any way to tackle this ?

Comment: you mean can't we apply spark structured streaming for aggregation for columns other than watermarking? very sad

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011002/multiple-aggregations-in-spark-structured-streaming

Comment: his issue is multiple aggregation... mine is only 1 aggregation

Comment: yes but you have a group by in the watermark thing to consider and then another aggr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495009/spark-structured-streaming-multiple-aggregation-keys-on-same-stream-data

Comment: i have tried below                             
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 df_agg_with_time.writeStream.outputMode("append").partitionBy("year").format("csv").
        option("path", "hdfs://doxdt/apps/hive/warehouse/rtdv_dev_landing_initial_area.db/sample_mov/").start()                    getting error below:    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186435/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-bigd).