# How to update HDFS files after every trigger?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write my processed data to HDFS location. I am getting data writing  to the HDFS location after long trial and error methods, BUT the issue now is whenever i add new files to my directory(where i am pointing for readStream) that the old file getting processed and updated in HDFS location

lets say i have started streaming and I have added file-1.csv in my directory...nothing is written to HDFS location..Then i have added file-2.csv..still its not getting written to HDFS , next i have added file-3.csv..this time the processed file of file-1.csv is getting written to HDFS...

```
File 1 - no prcess
File 2 - no process
File 3 - process and written file 1 data to HDFS
file4 - process and written file 2 data to HDFS
```

am not sure why it is happening even it is structured streaming

can somebody how to resolve this issue ?

my output command given below:

```
FetRepo
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .partitionBy("data_dt")
  .format("csv")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
  .option("path", "hdfs://ffff/apps/hive/warehouse/area.db/fin_repo/")
  .start
```

Comment: Does HDFS play a role here? Does this work if you use a regular file system? What Spark version is this? How do you run your Spark app?

Comment: The data is eventually being written though - or not?

Comment: @Jack Laskowski  Yes,,HDFS plays role.. i have created HIVE table on top of HDFS. spark 2.3.0 .. i have run through spark-shell

Comment: @thebluephantom  Data  written eventually, but as i said its not writting the data whenver i add new file.. always having 2 or files LAG... when i ingest file 3 , file 1 getting processed and inserted into HDFS as partition

Comment: I observed the same It is what it is. I would not worry.

Comment: can you please elaborate.. didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself "How often do I add the files?" and how does this relate to 
`Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")`? With the configuration you should not expect anything happen within 10 seconds.

Another thing to look at is that you use `outputMode("append")` that will only output rows for aggregations (groups) that were added since the last trigger.

From [Basic Concepts](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-concepts):

> **Append Mode** - Only the new rows appended in the Result Table since the last trigger will be written to the external storage.

Please note that (quoting the same document): *"This is applicable only on the queries where existing rows in the Result Table are not expected to change."*

Comment: yes... its not happening after 30 seconds also.. also my data is fresh and the hdfs location which i am inserting data also clean.... i can see this pattern of insertion after every 3 files addition to my readStream directory .... is there any settings /restriction regarding number of files on spark structured streaming  ?