# Spark Structured Streaming cannot writeStream in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using structured streaming and I'm trying to send my result into a kafka topic, named "results".

I get the following error:

```
'Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;
```

Can anyone help?

```
query1 = prediction.writeStream.format("kafka")\
  .option("topic", "results")\
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
  .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")\
  .start()
query1.awaitTermination()
```

prediction schema is:

```
root
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = false)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spark structured streaming exception : Append output mode not supported without watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117961/spark-structured-streaming-exception-append-output-mode-not-supported-without)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message gives a hint on what is missing: a watermark.

Watermarks are used to handle late incoming data when you are aggregating stream data. Details can be found in the Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking) for Structured Streaming.

It is important that withWatermark is used on the same column as the timestamp column used in the aggregate.

An example on how to use `withWatermark` is given in the Spark documentation:

```py
words = ...  # streaming DataFrame of schema { timestamp: Timestamp, word: String }

# Group the data by window and word and compute the count of each group
windowedCounts = words \
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes") \
    .groupBy(
        window(words.timestamp, "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
        words.word) \
    .count()
```